# when i select any input, it slides back to top in mobile

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

when I select any input, it slides back to the top in mobile    and everything is fine desktop

```
            <div class="footer">
                    <h3 class="footer-title"> Become a TN Subscriber</h3>
                    <p>For getting more updates on True Nature events and activities, Please subscribe</p>

                    <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" id="json">
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin processing"></i>

                    <form class="footer-newsletter" action="subscribe.php" method="post" id="subscribe">

                        <input style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="input" onkeypress="return /[a-zA-Z ]/i.test(event.key)" placeholder="Enter your Name" type="text" required name="name">


                        <input class="input" type="text" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.([^@\s]{2,})+"
                             placeholder="Enter your Email" name="email" required>

                        <button class="primary-button" type="submit">Subscribe to True Nature</button>

                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: What slides where, your footer? Input selected, how as in giving it focus? What css code do you have for your footer?

Comment: You're question isn't clear.  Please read [this useful guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you ask good questions and get relevant answers. :)

Comment: There could be various reasons, but your question lacks additional information. Aside from what has been asked already, what OS and browser are you using on your phone?